# error: not found: value assemblyJarName in assembly

Tags: scala, hadoop

I am new to big data and hadoop, I am trying to make use of hadoopcryptoledger library to do some bitcoin graph analysis, I followed this tutorial [Using spark-scala-graphx to analyze Bitcoin transaction graph](https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopcryptoledger/wiki/Using-Spark-Scala-Graphx-to-analyze-the-Bitcoin-transaction-graph)

While executing the command

```
sbt clean assembly test it:test
```

I ran into an issue:

```
/home/jnikhil/hadoopcryptoledger/examples/scala-spark-graphx-    
bitcointransaction/build.sbt:30: error: not found: value assemblyJarName
assemblyJarName in assembly := "example-hcl-spark-scala-graphx-bitcointransaction.jar"
```

Does anyone know why am I facing this issue?

Comment: Did you change into the subfolder /home/jnikhil/hadoopcryptoledger/examples/scala-spark-graphx-    
bitcointransaction/ ? What sbt version are you using? I cannot reproduce the error. Did you modify anything? Are you using an IDE? Please use at least sbt 0.13.5

Comment: it was sbt version issue. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[These instructions](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) give the answer.

Add the following to `project/assembly.sbt`:

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.8")
```